# Access variable as both function and class instance

Tags: javascript, typescript

How can I access a variable as both a function and an object instance with TypeScript?

```
log("something");

log.info("something");
```

I have tried many ways, like overriding prototype, but nothing seems to work:

```
var log = (...args) => {
   console.log(...args);
};

log.prototype.info = (...args) => console.info(...args);
```

Comment: `log.info = (...args) => ...`?

Comment: tried that too, not working. I can see the function def if I `console.log(log.info)`, but for some reason the call is ignored when I run it. Could it be that the ts compiler does not include my function call ?

Comment: What do you mean _"the call is ignored"_? And did you look at the actual compiler output (which won't generally just leave stuff out) to check?

Comment: Call is ignored? Where are you running the code?

Comment: It is possible though. Look at the `Number` constructor in JavaScript. You can call it both as a function, or with the `new` keyword. They simply use the old-school constructor function style and check if `this === undefined`, because `this` will not be defined if it wasn't instantiated with the `new` keyword, which allows you to know whether or not being called as a constructor or just as a function.

Comment: @mstephen19 The `new`-vs-no-`new` distinction is not what the OP tries to do. (Btw, you better check for `new.target`, not `this`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very possible using `Object.assign`

```
type Log = {
    (...args: any): void;
    info: (...args: any) => void;
};

const log: Log = Object.assign((...args: any) => console.log(...args), {
    info: (...args: any) => console.log('INFO:', ...args),
});

log('hello');

log.info('world');
```

Compiled:

```js
"use strict";
const log = Object.assign((...args) => console.log(...args), {
    info: (...args) => console.log('INFO:', ...args),
});
log('hello');
log.info('world');
```

You don't even need to create the `Log` type if you don't want to. TypeScript will automatically infer the types of the objects you're passing to `Object.assign` and create an intersection between them.

```
const log = Object.assign((...args: any) => console.log(...args), {
    info: (...args: any) => console.log('INFO:', ...args),
});

log('hello');

log.info('world');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely assign an `.info` property to the function object that you assigned to `log` in basic JavaScript.

```js
log = (...args) => console.log(...args);
log.info = (...args) => console.info(...args);

log("something");
log.info("something");
```

In TypeScript, qualify as desired, or with `: any[]`

```
const log = (...args: any[]) => console.log(...args);
log.info = (...args: any[]) => console.info(...args);
log("something");
log.info("something");
```

Thanks @HereticMonkey for the [TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBANiA5jAvDAFAOmwQwE6IQBcMOYAngNoC6AlKgHwyiQhwCmmCiWuBEtANwAobpgCWYAGYhUGbJnyESZKnUbNwENp0kzei-kOGik6AETaAtuygALSYnPGxekBeu2HYJ0KA).  **Note**: the `console.info` appears only in the developer tools, not in the TS playground's in-page log.

Comment: I think TypeScript will complain about the args; you need to add `(...args: any[])`.

Comment: The code snippet shows that it works in JavaScript, but not whether it is doable in TypeScript. A [TypeScript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBANiA5jAvDAFAOmwQwE6IQBcMOYAngNoC6AlKgHwyiQhwCmmCiWuBEtANwAobpgCWYAGYhUGbJnyESZKnUbNwENp0kzei-kOGik6AETaAtuygALSYnPGxekBeu2HYJ0KA) is usually appreciated for these kinds of questions.

Comment: Was definitely not aware that this is possible in TypeScript. When did they add this?